# Can't get program to approximate pi correctly

Tags: java, pi

I'm currently learning Java and one of my assignments is to approximate pi using a certain formula that the professor gave us and we must use a for loop. The directions weren't very clear to me but I have the program very close but I can't figure out why the value for pi is close but not what it should be at each interval.

This is the instructions I was given to do the program:

> (Compute π) You can approximate π by using the following formulas:
>   pi += sign / (2 * i - 1.0); where i is the name of a variable in a for loop and pi is the >name of the variable for π and sign has an initial value of 1 when it is declared and >within the for loop is set to equal the negative of itself. Make sure you use a for loop >for this assignment. The for loop's starting value should be 2 and ending value should be >when i is less than or equal to 100000. If the value of pi divided by 10000 is zero than >pi should be (4 * pi).

This is my code that I came up with.

```
public class Ch4PA1
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Declarations
double pi = 1;
double sign = 1;

for  (int i = 10000; i <= 100000; i += 10000)
{
    pi = 3.14159265359;
    sign = -2;
    pi += sign / (2 * i - 1.0);
    System.out.println("i : " + i + " The PI is " + pi);
}
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've been at this program for about 10 hours off an on and it just ends up in me getting frustrated as heck trying to figure it out.

Comment: I think you should re-read the instructions and look at your `for` loop.  `for(int i = 10000; i <= 100000; i += 10000)` is wrong, I think...

Comment: She says to use the initial value of 2 but she wants us to output the value of pi in 10,000 intervals from 10,000 to 100,000. I tried every single way possible to get it to work using her directions and this was the only way I could get it to show just the 10,000 intervals she wants. I think the issue I'm having is with the value of the sign variable but everything I try doesn't make much sense in the program because it makes pi wrong each time.

Comment: `for(int i = 2; //etc...`, then put your output in `if(i % 10000 == 0) { System.out.//etc...`  As your `for` loop currently stands, you're not doing the math frequently enough (nevermind any other errors) to get anywhere close to approximating `pi` because you're only running through your loop like 10 times.  You need to go through it like 100,000 times to get accurate.  `i % 10000 == 0` will return `true` when `i` is a multiple of `10000`, so it will print at `i=0`, `i=10000`, `i=20000`, etc.

Comment: Not terribly clear instructions, but they essentially want you to do reproduce this series: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: I just added that modification to my code. It does come out in the intervals but it's still not showing the same values of pi as her example showed in the picture. For example in her sample run she gets 3.1415826535897198 at 100,000. I end up with 3.1415826534 close but not exactly the same as what she got with her program.

This is really the first program in the class that has really confused me this badly.

Answer (score 0):

Look back at the instructions...they say "...sign has an initial value of 1 when it is declared and >within the for loop is set to equal the negative of itself". You are setting

```
sign = -2;
```

on every iteration.

They also say "The for loop's starting value should be 2...". You have

```
for  (int i = 10000; i <= 100000; i += 10000)
```

which makes the `for` loop's starting value 10000.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Ch4PA1
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Declarations
double pi = 1;
double sign = 1;

for  (int i = 2; i <= 100000; ++i) //Switched the starting value to 2, and the increment to 1
{
    pi = 3.14159265359;
    pi += sign / (2 * i - 1.0);
    if (sign > 0){ //you were constantly doing a -2 as oppose dto switching what the sign currently is. Notice I do it after your sign calculation so that it switches the sign AFTER the first iteration as instructed.
      sign = -1;
    }
    else sign = 1;

    System.out.println("i : " + i + " The PI is " + pi);
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand from the question, sign has an initial value of 1 when it is declared and within the for loop is set to equal the negative of itself.

```
    pi += (-sign) / (2 * i - 1.0);
```

The for loop definition should look more like below

```
    for(int i=2; i<=100000 ; i++)
```

I still do not understand the question and the reason why you incremented the loop variable i to 10000 after every loop.

There should also be an IF condition inside the loop as seen below

```
    if(pi/10000)
    pi *= 4
```